# Зачем в этом методе используем intersect

Tags: kotlin

Вот решаю простую задачу по Котлину

```
Implement Shop.getSetOfProductsOrderedByEveryCustomer() using fold.



data class Shop(val name: String, val customers: List<Customer>)

data class Customer(val name: String, val city: City, val orders: List<Order>) {
override fun toString() = "$name from ${city.name}"
}

data class Order(val products: List<Product>, val isDelivered: Boolean)

data class Product(val name: String, val price: Double) {
override fun toString() = "'$name' for $price"
}
```

Решение выглядит вот так

```
fun Shop.getSetOfProductsOrderedByEveryCustomer(): Set<Product> {
val allProducts = customers.flatMap { it.orders.flatMap { it.products }}.toSet()
return customers.fold(allProducts, {
    orderedByAll, customer ->
    orderedByAll.intersect(customer.orders.flatMap { it.products }.toSet())
})
}
```

Так вот насколько я понимаю, что вот этой строчки

```
val allProducts = customers.flatMap { it.orders.flatMap { it.products }}.toSet()
```

достаточно, чтоб получить список всех покупок.

Зачем выполнять `fold()` ?

Только из за условия задачи или в этом есть смысл?

Потому, что насколько я вижу то в данном случае он выполняет тоже самое...

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68014/discussion-on-question-by-aleksey-timoshchenko------in).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разгадка была простой, нужно было вернуть сет продуктов который состоит из продуктов которые есть в заказе у каждого из покупателей.

Скажем один заказал `А` `В` `С` а другой только `В` , так вот этот метод

```
getSetOfProductsOrderedByEveryCustomer()
```

(в описании моего вопроса) вернет сет который будет состоять всего из одного продукта `В`.

Так как он содержиться и у первого и у второго покупателя.